# How to check for multiple columns in a subquery?

Tags: mysql

I have a couple of tables in MySQL representing an undirected graph. The `Users` table has a `user_id` (and some other stuff I don't need right now), while the `Links` table has `user_id_1` and `user_id_2` (and some other data that I need to come along for the ride). I'm trying to get all the links between a given user's neighbors (including himself). My question, basically, is: how do I do this? I managed to get all of a user's neighbors, plus himself, with the following somewhat unfortunate query:

```
SELECT u.* FROM Users u
JOIN Links l ON u.user_id = l.user_id_1
WHERE l.user_id_2 = @arg
UNION
SELECT u.* FROM Users u
JOIN Links l ON u.user_id = l.user_id_2
WHERE l.user_id_1 = @arg
UNION
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE user_id = @arg
```

Now I want to select exactly those `Links` where both `user_id_1` and `user_id_2` appear in the above query. **Is there any way to do this without performing that query twice?** Because (although I haven't profiled it) I have this sneaking suspicion that the above query is pretty non-performant. As a secondary question, is there a better way to do the subquery?

Edit: Having been asked for sample data and output, here goes. I give the `Links` table here. I promise all of these users actually exist in the `Users` table, so you don't need to worry about joins failing or anything like that. However I think this question should be answerable without joining to `Users` at all.

```
link_id  user_id_1  user_id_2
1        A          B
2        C          B
3        C          A
4        D          C
5        C          E
6        D          E
7        A          D
8        F          A
```

If we then do this query for A, the `Users` query above should return everyone except E, who isn't a neighbor of A (all the others are). The query I'm looking for needs to return all of the `Links` in the table except 5 and 6, which involve E. In particular it needs to return 2 and 4, as well as the links directly involving A.

Comment: Please post some sample data from the two tables and the desired output.

Comment: Save the result of the query in a temp table, and then join with that.

Comment: @Barmar I was hoping to do this purely through JDBC without using a sproc. Mostly because my SQL isn't that strong and I don't really know how to use temp tables in MySQL. But if there's no other way, please write out the sproc I need in an answer and I'll probably accept it. Bonus points if the sproc returns both result sets at once.

Comment: No stored proc is necessary, just `create temporary table temp_users as <your subquery>`.

Comment: @Barmar Well, I tried writing a sproc, and I get the error "Can't reopen table". Apparently this is a known problem in MySQL? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/temporary-table-problems.html Pretty lame, IMO.

Comment: Oh, that's too bad. MySQL has some really annoying limitations like that.